# Unable to get proper bearing values

Tags: c++, kalman-filter, magnetometer

**AIM**: Read in filtered bearing values

**CONCERN**: The output is not accurate. Values returned are either all 0 or all 180.

**CODE STATUS**: Compiled successfully and running without any compiler warnings.

**SENSOR** : QMC5883L

**DETAILS** :

1. The magnetometer is functional. Verified with the help of a standalone python script.
2. Values are faulty even without the kalman filter.
3. Have to execute in c++ as the latter part of the project is done  in c++

following is my code and the related header files.

**compassvalscpp.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mycompass.h"
#include "mykalman.h"

int main(){
    bool init = true;
    kalman_state state;
compass * compass_sensor = new compass();
compass_sensor->start();
int i=0;
while(1){
    compass_sensor->update();
    if(init){       
        state = kalman_init(0.025f, 16, 1, compass_sensor->bearing);
        init = false;
        }
    kalman_update(&state, compass_sensor->bearing);
    float filtered_bearing = state.x;
    std::cout<<"filtered bearing = "<<filtered_bearing<<std::endl;
    }
delete compass_sensor;
return 0;}
```

**mycompass.h**

```
#ifndef __COMPASS_H__  
#define __COMPASS_H__
#define QMC5883L_I2C_ADDR 0x0D
#define M_PI = 3.1415926535
#include <iostream>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "mycompass.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stropts.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/i2c.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
bool init;
class compass{
private:
    int i2c_fd;
    bool select_i2c_device(int fd, int addr);
    bool write_to_i2c(int fd, int reg, int val);
public:
    float bearing;
    int start();
    int update();
};
bool compass::select_i2c_device(int fd, int addr){
    if (ioctl(fd,I2C_SLAVE, addr) < 0) {
        return false;}
    return true;}
bool compass::write_to_i2c(int fd, int reg, int val){
    char buf[2];
    buf[0]=reg;
    buf[1]=val;
    if (write(fd, buf, 2) != 2){
        return false;}
    return true;}
int compass::start(){
    init = true;
    if ((i2c_fd = open("/dev/i2c-1", O_RDWR)) < 0){
        return 0;}
    select_i2c_device(i2c_fd, QMC5883L_I2C_ADDR);
    write_to_i2c(i2c_fd, 0x0A, 0b10000000);
    write_to_i2c(i2c_fd, 0x0A, 0b00000001);
    write_to_i2c(i2c_fd, 0x0B, 0x01);
    write_to_i2c(i2c_fd, 0x09, 0b00000001);
    return 1;
}
int compass::update(){
    float angle = 0;
    unsigned char i2c_buf[16];
    i2c_buf[0] = 0x03;
    if ((write(i2c_fd, i2c_buf, 1)) != 1){
        return 0;}
    if (read(i2c_fd, i2c_buf, 6) != 6){
        return 0;} 
    else{
        short x = (i2c_buf[1] << 8) | i2c_buf[0];
        short y = (i2c_buf[3] << 8) | i2c_buf[2];
    x = x*0.00092;
    y = y*0.00092;
        angle = atan2(y, x) * 180 / M_PI;}
    bearing = angle;
    return 1;
}
#endif
```

**mykalman.h**

```
#ifndef __KALMAN_H__  
#define __KALMAN_H__

typedef struct {
    float q; //process noise covariance
    float r; //measurement noise covariance
    float x; //value
    float p; //estimation error covariance
    float k; //kalman gain
} kalman_state;

kalman_state kalman_init(float q, float r, float p, float x);

void kalman_update(kalman_state *s, float m);

kalman_state kalman_init(float q, float r, float p, float x) {
    kalman_state s;
    s.q = q;
    s.r = r;
    s.p = p;
    s.x = x;

    return s;
}

void kalman_update(kalman_state * s, float m) {
    //prediction update
    //omit x = x
    s->p = s->p + s->q;

    //measurement update
    s->k = s->p / (s->p + s->r);
    s->x = s->x + s->k * (m - s->x);
    s->p = (1 - s->k) * s->p;
}

#endif // __KALMAN_H__
```

Comment: Is the sensor faulty? Perhaps the decoding of the sensor protocol? Your filter could be causing problems, too, just as the output. Protocol decoding and filtering should be unit-tested, so that you are sure that there is nothing wrong with it. In any case, use a debugger to go through the code and to find out where things go wrong or at least in which part of the code things go wrong. Also, turn on compiler warnings. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask] as well.

Comment: Just skimming over your code, there's a lot that could be improved as well. After getting it to run, submit your code for review at codereview.stackexchange.com, you won't regret it!

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @UlrichEckhardt ! I have made a few changes to better present my problem. I hope to get some more help as I am a little bit stuck

Comment: Probably unrelated: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) Breaking these naming rules doesn't bite all that often, but when it does, it bites hard. The results can be utterly bizarre.

Comment: Tactical note: If you need a comment after a variable declaration to explain what the variable represents, the variable's name is probably insufficient.

Comment: If your development tools have a debugging utility that allows you to step through the code running on the device, definitely make use of it. If it doesn't do send semi-regular diagnostics to the  console. For example, printing out `x` and `y` in `compass::update` and ake sure it matches expectations. If that's good, make sure `angle` has the correct value, etc... until you spot the variable with the wrong value.

Comment: Oh okay, I’ll try to look into it, thanks for your inputs as well @user4581301

Comment: Note: scaling `x = x*0.00092; y = y*0.00092;` not needed.  Angle is the same without it.

Comment: Oh okay thanks, but still the values aren't fixing